# Keep mesh name after Grease Pencil convert

Tags: mesh, grease-pencil

Is there a way to retain a mesh's name after converting it to a Grease Pencil object? For example, when a mesh object named 'cube' is converted into a Grease Pencil object, the mesh object's name 'cube' is eliminated and the new Grease Pencil object is called 'GPencil'. I have a collection of meshes that need to be converted to Grease Pencil objects. But if I write a script to automate this, the names of the mesh will be lost.

Comment: in the script u can get the name of the object and assign it to the gpencil object after conversion

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie works but not for multiple objs?  
    `import bpy  
#from the blender scripts batch export template  
selection = bpy.context.selected_objects  
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')  
for obj in selection:  
    obj.select_set(True)  
    #get object name & store in variable mesh_name  
    mesh_name = bpy.context.active_object.name  
    #convert object to Gpencil object  
    bpy.ops.object.convert(target='GPENCIL')      
    #assign mesh's name to Gpencil object  
    bpy.context.active_object.name = mesh_name      
    obj.select_set(False)`

Comment: Keep getting error: ReferenceError: StructRNA of type Object has been removed  
on the line of code `obj.select_set(False)`